# Android - How to refer to multiple id at one time using foreign key, SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, many-to-many

i am trying to insert an expense that refer to many friends. But using foreign key, it can only refer to a friendId, but each friend can have many expenses, and a expense can shared by many friends. How can i implement this relationship? Maybe not using foreign key? Can anyone give me idea of doing that? Thanks.

This is my create database code:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String query, query1, query2, query3;
    query = "CREATE TABLE events ( eventId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, eventName TEXT, eventDate TEXT, eventLocation TEXT, eventDescription TEXT);";
    query1 = "CREATE TABLE friends ( friendId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, friendName TEXT, friendNumber TEXT, friendEmail TEXT, friendSpending DOUBLE, friendEvent INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(friendEvent) REFERENCES events(eventId) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
    query2 = "CREATE TABLE expenses ( expenseId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, expenseName TEXT, expenseType TEXT, expensePrice REAL, expenseQuantity INTEGER, expenseEvent INTEGER REFERENCES events(eventId) ON DELETE CASCADE, expenseFriend INTEGER REFERENCES friends(friendId) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
    query3 = "CREATE TABLE temporary (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, spendingId INTEGER)";
    database.execSQL(query);
    database.execSQL(query1);
    database.execSQL(query2);
    database.execSQL(query3);
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "events Created");
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "friends Created");
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "expenses Created");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A many-to-many relationship cannot be represented with a column in either table.
You have to create a separate table with a record for each friend/expense combination:

```
CREATE TABLE friends ( friendId ...);
CREATE TABLE expenses ( expenseId ...);
CREATE TABLE FriendsExpenses(
    friendId  INTEGER REFERENCES friends(firendId),
    expenseId INTEGER REFERENCES expenses(expenseId),
    PRIMARY KEY (friendId, expenseId)
);
```

Comment: thanks, how to delete the expense that refer to the friendId if the friendId deleted?